# How to animate a Popup when it hides?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, popup, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

i created a `Popup Style` for using in my windows 8.1 application.  And i applied `PopupThemeTransition` to it's `ChildTransitions` Property.

```
<Style x:Key="AnimatedPopupStyle" TargetType="Popup">
    <Setter Property="IsLightDismissEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ChildTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <PopupThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My problem is that it animates when it Opens & not animating  when closing. What to do with that for animating the content on hiding ? Do i want to create a Custom Popup control? 
**NB:** I know that `PopInThemeAnimation` & `PopOutThemeAnimation` is there . But don't know how to use it on this condition ?

Comment: What was the reason for not wanting to use the theme?

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT sorry , What you mean it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not native to the Popup because they typically do not have an exit animation. Having said that, there's no reason you can't add an exit animation to a Popup control.

Try this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowPopup">
            <PopInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="HidePopup">
            <PopOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Popup x:Name="MyPopup" IsOpen="True"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Popup.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <PopupThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Popup.Transitions>
        <Grid Height="200" Width="200" Background="Red">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Hide (Native)" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                            <Core:ChangePropertyAction 
                                PropertyName="IsOpen" 
                                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MyPopup}" />
                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
                <Button Content="Hide (Storyboard)" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                            <Media:ControlStoryboardAction 
                                Storyboard="{StaticResource HidePopup}"/>
                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Show Popup (Native)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction 
                        TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MyPopup}" 
                        PropertyName="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Show Popup (Storyboard)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction 
                        TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MyPopup}" 
                        PropertyName="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction 
                        Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPopup}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Using these:

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
```

Best of luck!

Comment: if you are using storboards to show/hide something I would also suggest not even using a Popup. Just use a grid and then you do not need to worry about the IsOpen property

Comment: Let me think about that, Shawn. The two core benefits of a Popup are its ability to inject itself into the visual tree and the ability to handle a light dismiss. Since he has disabled light dismiss, the only other is the tree thing. And how hard is that? Actually, it's not super easy, but not that hard. Your recommendation is fine - but, having said that, what's the harm? It's quite light weight.

Comment: Exactly get what I am looking for. Thanks and +1 for help.