# How to animate the hiding procedure of a pop up (whose IsLightDismissEnabled is set as True)?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I've posted [a thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f4af9143-fc1c-4ba4-b7d2-747277fe5d4b/how-to-animate-the-hiding-procdure-of-a-pop-upwhose-islightdismissenabled-is-set-as-true?forum=winappswithnativecode#f4af9143-fc1c-4ba4-b7d2-747277fe5d4b) but gotten no reply so far. So I am turning to StackOverflow...

For the opening animation, it is quite easy. But for the closing/hiding, it seems that there is no direct way to achieve this effect.
The settings pane and the bottom/top app bar have the animation effects for both opening && hiding.
There has been a discussing thread here:
[How to animate a Popup when it hides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111162/how-to-animate-a-popup-when-it-hides)
But IsLightDismissEnabled is set as False in that case.

Would you please give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I would make the `Popup` full screen, create a (transparent?) background panel to handle light dismiss input manually and put any other content inside of that panel. When you detect a tap on the panel - run any animation you want and when it completes - set `IsOpen = false`.

Comment: Hi, Filip, that's really a great solution. It seems a little aggressive to our app at present. But I'd like to try it...Thanks.