# How do I animate popup element in WinRT

Tags: popup, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make fade in and fade out animation for popup element in WinRT application (for windows 8.1).

I tried with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752079(v=vs.110).aspx
but I can't set this to my popup:

```
   AllowsTransparency="True"
   PopupAnimation="Slide"
```

Is there a way to do it in WinRT?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Transitions and ChildTransitions for Popup in WinRT. There are several Transitions available like PopupThemeTransition, ContentThemeTransition etc. You can refer similar answer in following link,

[How to animate a Popup when it hides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111162/how-to-animate-a-popup-when-it-hides)